# Create 4K video with Mjpeg codec in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to produce a simple 6 seconds video clip by zooming on an image (.mov output, mjpeg codec). I can get this command to work when I set the output to be 1920x1080:

```
ffmpeg -y -r 25 -nostdin -loop 1 -i input.jpg -vf "zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':d=700:x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)'" -c:v mjpeg -qscale:v 1 -t 6 -s "1920x1080" "test/output.mov"
```

but it's not working anymore when I set the output to be 4K (3840x2160): the command hangs, is killed or produces a corrupted output.

My input.jpg resolution is 4240x2832.

What am I missing?

Edit: here is the full log:

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[mjpeg @ 0x151da00] Changeing bps to 8
Input #0, image2, from 'input.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 760992 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 4240x2832, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[swscaler @ 0x153cf80] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
Output #0, mov, to 'test/output.mov':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (jpeg / 0x6765706A), yuvj444p(pc), 3840x2160, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 mjpeg
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> mjpeg (native))
[swscaler @ 0x43c82c0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x43c82c0] Warning: data is not aligned! This can lead to a speedloss
[swscaler @ 0x43c7dc0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x444d0a0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x444cdc0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
    Last message repeated 5 times
[swscaler @ 0x4439e20] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
    Last message repeated 6 times
[swscaler @ 0x43df9c0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
    Last message repeated 83 times
[output stream 0:0 @ 0x15240c0] 100 buffers queued in output stream 0:0, something may be wrong.
[swscaler @ 0x43df9c0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
creer_videos.sh: line 10:    18 Killed                  ffmpeg -y -r 25 -nostdin -loop 1 -i input.jpg -vf "zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':d=700:x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)'" -c:v mjpeg -qscale:v 1 -t 6 -s "3840x2160" "test/output.mov"
```

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: Upgrade to 4.1 and check. You may need to add `-pix_fmt yuv420p` for wide compatibility. Also add `:s=4240x2832` to the zoompan options for better quality.

Comment: @Gyan Upgrading worked, thanks